# How to view another jPanel containing many sub-jPanels from same JFrame in netbeans (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing

I want to show another jPanel from a button event action.
e.g.

```
private void jButtonMouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    update(getGraphics());
    //code to show another jPanel containing different sub-panels
}
```

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#card), see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633999/how-to-add-action-to-a-button/34637817#34637817) to give you an idea

Comment: Anything I can do in `AbsoluteLayout`? @Frakcool

Comment: Don't use it. `AbsoluteLayout` = `null layout` = [Null layout is evil](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-java/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [frowned upon to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)... Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520492/jtable-not-showing-up-on-jframe-java/42521097#42521097) of what happens when you use them...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help!

Comment: When I use `CardLayout`, I am able to use only one panel at a time, isn't there a way to add multiple panels in one frame and then after an event switch to another set of multiple panels within same frame? @Frakcool

Comment: Use GridBag layout to hold more than one sub components. Use a CardLayout to switch cards. It is best to use a GUI editor to place the components. It will generate complex Gridbag Layout for you. Never use absolute layout unless it is a quick prototype.

Answer (score 1):

> When I use `CardLayout`, I am able to use only one panel at a time, isn't there a way to add multiple panels in one frame and then after an event switch to another set of multiple panels within same frame?

Exactly, you can show only one `JPanel` everytime with `CardLayout` but that doesn't prevent you to show multiple `JPanel`s when using it...

You need to make the `card` (the `JPanel` that is shown in the current view) to show multiple `JPanel`s.

For example:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CardLayoutWithMultiplePanes {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;
    private JPanel cardsPane;
    private JPanel[] cards;
    private CardLayout cl;
    private JButton nextButton;
    private JButton previousButton;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CardLayoutWithMultiplePanes()::createAndShowGui);
    }
    
    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        
        previousButton = new JButton("Previous");
        nextButton = new JButton("Next");
        
        cl = new CardLayout();
        cardsPane = new JPanel(cl);
        cards = new JPanel[2];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            cards[i] = new JPanel();
            cards[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            cards[i].add(new CustomPane((i + 1) % 2 == 0 ? Color.BLUE : Color.RED));
            cards[i].add(new CustomPane((i + 1) % 2 == 0 ? Color.GREEN : Color.MAGENTA));
            
            cardsPane.add(cards[i]);
        }
        
        Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box.add(previousButton);
        box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box.add(nextButton);
        
        previousButton.addActionListener(listener);
        nextButton.addActionListener(listener);
        
        pane.add(cardsPane);
        pane.add(box);
        
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    private ActionListener listener = e -> {
        if (e.getSource().equals(previousButton)) {
            cl.previous(cardsPane);
        } else if (e.getSource().equals(nextButton)) {
            cl.next(cardsPane);
        }
    };
    
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class CustomPane extends JPanel {
        private Color color;
        
        public CustomPane(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

[image] [image]

The above code shows a single `JPanel` that contains 2 more `JPanel`s, in which each `JPanel` has its own background color (and might contain their own components such as `JLabel` or `JButton`, etc)

I hope this gives you an idea for what you're trying to do.

### Note:

- Imagine your `JFrame` as a notebook.
- Imagine the `JPanel`s as the sheets.
- Imagine `CardLayout` as your finger passing pages (back and forward)

In every sheet (`JPanel`) you can have whatever you want (even more than 1 sheet (glued to it)), it's the same principle here